# Список с изменяющимся порядком объектов

Tags: база-данных, алгоритм

Есть список объектов. Они расположены в определенном порядке. Этот порядок можно настраивать перетаскиванием объекта вниз или вверх.

Как это реализовать алгоритмически?

Учитывая, что эти объекты хранятся в таблице, например items. И саму информацию о порядке надо в базе хранить.

Comment: Ввести дополнительное поле, в котором хранится порядок элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Если список не так часто меняется обычно используют простой массив. А смена порядка как всегда `swap`. Если элементы списка по размеру больше, чем 8 байт (64 бит), тогда в таблице хранят указатели. Так проще делать своппинг. Если очень часто происходит изменение размера таблицы, то можно подумать о дву-связных списках, но практически это делать не советуют, так как список занимает память в два раза больше и скорость обслуживания этого списка уменьшается до величины O(0). Добавьте в вопросе на каком языке будет реализация.

Comment: Не имеет значения, какой язык. Как это в базе данных заложить?

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, вполне очевидно, что надо

- добавить в таблицу в БД поле (назвать, например, как-нибудь вроде `object_sequence` или `object_order`)
- формировать данные для поля на клиенте во время сотрировки
- отправлять на сервер набор пар чисел `(<ID объекта>, <новый порядковый номер>)`, а дальше уже `UPDATE`/`MERGE` или что там у вас за СУБД и что она умеет.

Для вывода объектов в сохраненном порядке просто дописать к запросу (если у вас SQL) `order by object_order`

Comment: А что это поле будет содержать? Int значение? И если мы с самого конца передвигаем элемент в начало, нам надо инкрементировать все значения в бд для предыдущих записей? Такая задумка, правильно я вас понял?

Comment: Да, как-то так. У меня на текущем проекте во многих местах такое используется (пользователь задает порядок следования элементов перетаскиванием на экране). Пользователь что-то там перетаскивает туда-сюда, мы потом просто берем, заново генерируем последовательность и отправляем все на сервер, а там все обновляем. Нет смысла долго возиться, определять, что поменялось, а что нет, потому что в итоге все равно получится в лучшем случае экономия на спичках, а в худшем - куча лишнего сложного кода, который еще и поддерживать надо.